# What are all the id's in R file?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources

I read that in order to create a new id we should use the *@+ prefix*, and when program is generated the id is added as an int to R file. In addition i read the when we asking for an id that is part of android platform and not part of R file, we will use *@android:* prefix.
**But,** when i have open the R file, in addition to the id's i have added i saw a lot of id's. From where they come, if it says that the android platform id's aren't part to the R file?
I think it's relevant for all inner classes inside R file, there are a lot of inner classes inside R file with many final int attributes that weren't added by me.
BTW, i realize the there are **a lot** of R files inside androidx parent folder, and only one R that is part of my project (under com folder), but all i have wrote refer to my project R file class which contains **a lot** of inner class with **a lot** of final int that weren't added by me.

In addition i very curious how an id is searched in androidx if there is such a lot of R files. for example i was search for R file that contains **@android:drawable/ic**_menu_camera but i didn't find it although my code was compiled when using this image